# When is the MvcHandler.ProcessRequest method called and by who?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I saw a function called `ProcessRequest` inside the `MvcHandler`, but I'm unable to figure out when will it be called?

When will it be called and who/what will call it?

Comment: After getting HttpContextBase a call is made to the internal version of ProcessRequest() method, passing HttpContextBase parameter to it. The call is then further to ProcessRequestInit(), which is responsible for extracting controllers name from RouteData collection and request controller factory to create corresponding controller.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/595520/MvcRouteHandler-and-MvcHandler-in-ASP-NET-MVC-Fram

Comment: You must search for a class that implements IHttpHandler contract because it only expose one method, the ProcessRequest() one. Great topic.

Comment: but who will call that method and at what point of time(I mean, at what event in the application life cycle)

Answer (score 4):

It is called by the ASP .Net pipeline, as part of its lifecycle and the specific steps taken when using routes.

When an mvc route matches the current request, its [`MvcRouteHandler`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/MvcRouteHandler.cs) returns the `IHttpHandler` that will process the request. In this case, an `MvcHandler` is returned:

```
protected virtual IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    requestContext.HttpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior(GetSessionStateBehavior(requestContext));
    return new MvcHandler(requestContext);
}
```

The class [`MvcHandler`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/MvcHandler.cs) implements [`IHttpHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is an ASP interface used to define handlers for http requests.

All of this happens as part of the standard [ASP. Net application lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx), where the [`UrlRoutingModule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.urlroutingmodule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is finding the matching route, getting its route handler, and finally the IHttpHandler. That is returned to ASP which will later call `ProcessRequest` (You can see it as the step 15 of the [*request is processed by the HttpApplication pipeline*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx) section).

PS. There is a very nice and MVC specific pipeline diagram [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application)

Comment: If I'm calling the (Modules["UrlRoutingModule-4.0"] as UrlRoutingModule).GetHandler(Request.RequestContext); inside the Application_BeginRequest events, I'm getting the output directly into the browser. here how come asp.net knows that it got the HttpHandler object and sending the response to the browser

Comment: I don't understand your question, you are trying to manually emulate what asp.net does? Also, there is no GetHandler in the UrlRoutingModule?

Comment: sry its (Modules["UrlRoutingModule-4.0"] as UrlRoutingModule).RouteHandler.GetHandler(Request.RequestContext);

Comment: I am still not sure I understand. So you are manually doing that in Application_BeginRequest, in the context of an MVC application. What do you mean with *get the output directly into the browser*? Do you mean that you get the output because you added that line to Application_BeginRequest?

Comment: try to put the break point at that statement and observe it in visual studio.. you'll get to know what i'm telling

Comment: I guess it's not BeginRequest event..... it's in Application_PostResolveRequestCache